# File API base 64 encoding for multiple images from html page to servlet

Tags: javascript, html, servlets, base64

Basically my requirment is that I have to upload 4 to 12 small icons(6kb) and 15-20 medium size icons (say 200kb) icons.

I have an html page that uploads multiple image using base 64 encoding to servlet using POST request. This base 64 string is converted into bytes to create image in server side code.

The POST request works fine to upload any no of small sized images(7kb) and 6-7 medium sized icons(200 kb). But when I am uploading more than 8 medium sized icons, the html page fails to carry data from html page to servlet. Even in my servlet when I do (sipReq.getParameter("name"))for other attributes the values are getting as null.

Please help for possible solution or I should look for some other alternative.

Comment: have you explored a multi-part request as a way to upload the images rather than converting them to strings? Also do you know the post size limit of your server? I expect it to be more than 2mb for your 8 images

Comment: As an FYI, if you are using Tomcat the default post limit is 2mb.

Comment: Something like [this](http://trentrichardson.com/2009/06/05/meet-jquery-iframer/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Commons' [FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) may well be the solution for you - I've had no problem with multiple, multi-megabyte simultaneous document uploads on Tomcat thanks to its multi-part support, as hinted at by @Sean.

If you're already using Spring MVC, it can be as simple as adding a [single extra bean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s08.html).